# Use Generic type to specify exception type

Tags: c#

Is it OK to use Generic type to specify Exception type?

to clarify what I mean, please see ***TEmptyTitle***, ***TLengthTitle***, ***TSpecialCharacter*** in the following code:

```
public class AggregateTitle<TEmptyTitle, TLengthTitle, TSpecialCharacter> : ValueObject
    where TEmptyTitle : BusinessException, new()
    where TLengthTitle : BusinessException, new()
    where TSpecialCharacter : BusinessException, new()
{
    private const string InvalidCharacters = "$&@#";
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    private AggregateTitle(string title)
    {
        Value = title;
    }

    public static AggregateTitle<TEmptyTitle, TLengthTitle, TSpecialCharacter> Create(string title)
    {
        GuardAgainstEmptyTitle<TEmptyTitle>(title);
        GuardAgainstTitleLengthenMoreThan256Characters<TLengthTitle>(title);
        GuardAgainstSpecialCharacters<TSpecialCharacter>(title);
        return new AggregateTitle<TEmptyTitle, TLengthTitle, TSpecialCharacter>(title);
    }

    private static void GuardAgainstSpecialCharacters<TSpecialCharacter>(string title)
        where TSpecialCharacter : BusinessException, new()
    {
        if (InvalidCharacters.Any(title.Contains))
            throw new TSpecialCharacter();
    }

    private static void GuardAgainstTitleLengthenMoreThan256Characters<TLengthTitle>(string title)
        where TLengthTitle : BusinessException, new()
    {
        if (title.Length > 256)
            throw new TLengthTitle();
    }

    private static void GuardAgainstEmptyTitle<TEmptyTitle>(string title)
        where TEmptyTitle : BusinessException, new()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            throw new TEmptyTitle();
    }
}
```

If it is not, what is the problem with using Generic for specifying Exception type?
and what is the correct way to implement a code that has different Exception types depending on where it will be used?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work, although I don't understand why you would ever want to do this. Are you actually likely to need multiple different exception types for `TLengthTitle` for example?

Comment: As you said, I am going to throw different Exceptions depending on where I will use the AggregateTitle<,,>. I was thinking about any kind of design mistake or abusing Generic usage. because I haven't seen this kind of Generic usage at all. @Charlieface

Comment: This likely works, but most of the time, it's just not necessary to have so many exception types. Do you really need to distinguish all those cases? You could also include an error code in the exception, if you need to later know how to handle which error.

Comment: @PMF Imagine I have two scenarios in my specifications. In the first one when I define a new instance from Aggregate1 which has an AggregateTitle, I will receive an exception with Code-1. In the second scenario, When I define a new instance of Aggregate2 which has an AggregateTitle, I will receive an exception with Code-2. This is the reason that I have made my AggregateTitle generic at first.

Comment: I can halfway see what you intent to do, but you could, instead of providing the generic types, also just provide an enum with the error you want as parameter.

Comment: @PMF by doing that, whenever I use AggregateTitle in a new Aggregate (for example Aggregate3), I have to extend the enum and modify The AggregateTitle to be able to handle new items of the enum too.